# Get current position with jquery ui map (gmap)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-ui-map

I'm upgrading an old hybrid application. 
Now I have the latest versions of *jQuery (1.7 -> 2.2.4)* and *jQuery Mobile (1.1 -> 1.4.5)*, and I use too Jquery Migrate (1.4.1).
This app contains a page with a map created with **jquery-ui-map** and I'm testing the app with **PhoneGap**.
In this page, I have a button and I would like to get current position of user.
I use this code:

```
    $('#button-getcurrentposition').click(function(){

        $('#map-canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(position, status) {

            alert("I'm here");

            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                $('#map-canvas').gmap('option','center', clientPosition);   
            }
        });         

    });
```

but the alert "*I'm here*" never displays and I don't know why, so I can not have the current position of the user.
I have included **jquery.ui.map.extensions.js**, **jquery.ui.map.overlays.js** and **jquery.ui.map.services.js**. 
 I have the same problem with the web app version and the apk or ipa.
Is there someone with the same problem? Does anyone know why the alert "*I'm here*" doesn't display? Is the function "**getCurrentPosition**" deprecated with the latest version of jquery or cordova?
 Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $('#button-getcurrentposition').click(function(){

        $('#map-canvas').gmap('getCurrentPosition', function(status, position) {

            alert("I'm here");

            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                $('#map-canvas').gmap('option','center', clientPosition);   
            }
        }, { timeout: 4000, enableHighAccuracy: true });        

    });
```

I believe these after parts are required and you have the variables in the function the wrong way around according to the docs.

Comment: OMG! Works! Thank you so much! But now I have another problem. The status is "object positionError". Do you know something about this error? Thanks

Comment: @Giu what line is that error? in the code context above

Comment: The variable "status" contains "object positionError". If I print alert(status); returns "positionError". Code: if ( status === 'OK' )

Comment: status becomes a positionError object if the location cannot be retrieved. You need to check if status is not a instance of a class first before `status === 'OK'`

Comment: mmmh, it's quite ok... i'm not sure to understand what do you mean with "check if status is not a instance of a class"... but why the location cannot be retrieved? What are the reasons? Is it a problem of code or I need to include something permission in android manifest?